# Python matplotlib: how to plot vertical bars with both a bottom and a top value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to plot bars which do not all start from the same baseline and have their own top value, but rather specify both a bottom and a top value?

In other words if I had the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'Seconds':[10,20,30,40],'SYS':[95,103,99,112],'DIA':[56,75,62,70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and from this I would need to show 4 bars, with the 'Seconds" values on the X axis and four bars which would start with at the df['DIA'] value and the top of the bar at the df['SYS'] value.

Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Plotting directly with pandas: 1) `df['top'] = df.SYS.sub(df.DIA)` 2) `df.plot(x='Seconds', y='top', kind='bar', bottom=df.DIA, rot=0, legend=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.bar(
    x=df['Seconds'],
    height=df['SYS'] - df['DIA'],
    bottom=df['DIA'],
)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `height=df['SYS'] - df['DIA']` in that case.

Comment: @paime you are correct -- I updated to fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: The standard import for pyplot is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: I'm not a fan of importing with aliases, especially for modules with shortish names like `pandas`, `numpy` and `pyplot`.  I always use the full `import pandas`, `import numpy` and `from matplotlib import pyplot`.  I know it goes against the grain of most answers on here, but I will continue my quixotic quest. :-)

Comment: Thank you all very much. I do see the merit of not using aliases, although in certain cases it can make things clearer (eg datetime) :) I do thinkthat code clarity trumps terseness though.